# How to save urdu language characters in a csv file?

Tags: python

I am trying to save urdu in csv file but symbols are stored in the file rather than urdu text also i have tried to add the iso code for urdu encoding but it is not working `ISO-8859-1`

```
import sys
import json
import time
import csv
import codecs

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_key, consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token, access_token_secret)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
tweets = api.search(q="اردو"+" -filter:retweets",count="10000")
for tweet in tweets:
  if tweet.lang == "ur":
    #print(tweet.text)
    with open('mytweets18.csv', 'w', encoding='ISO-8859-1') as f:
     writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=';')
     writer.writerow(tweet.text)
```

The problem is with encoding. I have also tried with `encoding="utf-8"`, but both are not working. Need help regarding this.

Comment: How are you checking the content of the file? Are you reading it back in python or open it in an external text editor?

Comment: Please describe in detail how it's "not working".

Comment: `ISO-8859-1` is just a UTF-8 enconding for first 256 chars of ASCII, it's not an Urdu specific encoding

Comment: i am opening it in excel it is showing jerbish characters

Answer (score 2):

The [ISO-8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1) character set (also called Latin-1) only includes 256 characters, mostly from Western Europe. As a result it cannot represent the characters you want to save.

[UTF-8](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) on the the other hand can store just about anything you can think of (and then some) supporting all unicode characters. When in doubt, this is the encoding to use.

The following code demonstrates saving and loading a CSV file with the text from your example:

```
import csv

data = u"ردو"


with(open('example.csv', 'w', encoding='utf-8')) as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    writer.writerow([data])

with(open('example.csv', encoding='utf-8')) as fh:
    for row in csv.reader(fh):
        print(row[0], len(row[0]))   
        # 3 ردو  (it seems backwards but Urdu is right-to-left)
```

You can see the number of characters is preserved correctly. This is important because UTF-8 stores characters as multiple bytes. If you load these as '`iso-8859-1`' for example, you will get jibberish like:

```
# Ø±Ø¯Ù 6
```

Which can be deceptive, as your terminal can hide the difference from you by re-interpreting the bytes as UTF-8, making it look like everything is working.

Comment: can you help up with my question i will be thankful to u

Comment: Sorry. I have tried to be. In your question you say "it isn't working", but my snippet above shows saving and loading the characters correctly. Can you give any more detail? Can you give an error if you are seeing one?